# How to make changes to the visibility of a div element in HTML based on the value typed into a input field such as a search bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a small text field where I want the user to enter a location (or any string) - Based on that entry that is typed - I want to change the visibility of a div based on the typed text. Here is some code of the "form" i am working with:

```
<div class="form-group">


<label>Location:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="search_input" placeholder="Type address..." />
<--! <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit"> -->


</div>
```

and this is the script I was planning on using:

```
<script>

function myFunction() {
if (document.getElementById(search_input)) = "Abu Dhabi - United Arab Emirates") {
document.getElementById("inzone").style.display = 'inline';

else
    {
        document.getElementById("outzone").style.display = 'none';
    }
 }
</script>
```

Actually I'm using the google Places Autocomplete API to fetch some relevant location into the text field  - So when someone chooses a place its then displayed in the input bar - When it is displayed in that bar I want the div titled "outzone" to be hidden.

Hope I was clear.

Oh - Here is the JS code for the googleAPI i was using:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&key=API"></script>

<script>var searchInput = 'search_input';

$(document).ready(function () {
var autocomplete;
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById(searchInput)), {
    types: ['geocode'],
componentRestrictions: {
    country: "AE"
} /* */
});

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
    var near_place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    //document.getElementById('loc_lat').value = near_place.geometry.location.lat();
   // document.getElementById('loc_long').value = near_place.geometry.location.lng();
    
   // document.getElementById('latitude_view').innerHTML = near_place.geometry.location.lat();
    //document.getElementById('longitude_view').innerHTML = near_place.geometry.location.lng();
});
});

$(document).on('change', '#'+searchInput, function () {
  //  document.getElementById('latitude_input').value = '';
 //document.getElementById('longitude_input').value = '';

//   document.getElementById('latitude_view').innerHTML = '';
// document.getElementById('longitude_view').innerHTML = '';
 });

</script>
```

I'm guessing I could do something with the Input Value ?

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Also try classList.toggle: `document.getElementById("search_input").addEventListener("input",function() { document.getElementById("outzone").classList.toggle("hide",!this.value.includes("Abu Dhabi"))});`

Comment: @mplungjan I want a div's visibility to be affected based on the value in the text box/input area.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to check the `value` of the input element every time that you type in the search input. You can do this by either listening to the `input` or `change` event on the search element.

Select the search input element and listen for either event with the [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method. The first parameter is a string with the event to listen to and the second parameter a function which will be called every time the event is fired on this element. This function is sometimes called an *event handler*.

Inside the event handler check if the `value` (which is the value that you entered in the input) is equal to the string that you want to compare it with.

Then instead of using the `style` property on the elements that you want to display or hide, use CSS classes which you can add or remove. This keeps your styling and functionality separated. Also, inline styles can only be overwritten by an `!important` statement or by overwriting them with JavaScript, which makes your CSS less flexible and harder to work with.

```js
const searchInput = document.getElementById('search_input');
const inZone = document.getElementById('inzone')
const outZone = document.getElementById('outzone')

searchInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
  if (searchInput.value === 'Abu Dhabi - United Arab Emirates') {
    inZone.classList.remove('hide');
    outZone.classList.add('hide');
  } else {
    inZone.classList.add('hide');
    outZone.classList.remove('hide');
  }
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `myFunction` as `onChange` handler for input:

```
<input type="text"
  class="form-control"
  id="search_input"
  placeholder="Type address..."
  onChange="myFunction()"
/>
```

Adjust `myFunction`:

```
<script>

function myFunction(evt) {
  if (evt.target.value === "Abu Dhabi - United Arab Emirates") {
    document.getElementById("inzone").style.display = 'inline';
  }else{
    document.getElementById("outzone").style.display = 'none';
  }
}
</script>
```

Your `myFunction` had 3 typos:

1. non-matching parentheses in your `if` condition
2. using assignment (`=`) rather than comparison (`===`)
3. missing brace before `else`

Comment: thanks for pointing out the corrections - I feel embarrassed. 

However still - there is no change in the visibility of the divs :(